# Cannot implicitly convert type `Xamarin.Forms.Color' to `FakeGDI.Color' with special coding considerations

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, xamarin, gdi

Im attempting to reuse legacy Windows GDI code in Xamarin without modifying the legacy GDI code (except using #if). In this specific case I need to use Color from Xamrin.Forms wrapped in my own color struct. I get the error cannot convert as posted in the question header above.

This is the legacy code that is not to be modified (or very little)

```
#if WINDOWS
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;
#else //if Xamarin
using FakeGDI;  //cannot specify 'using Xamarin.Forms;' in legacy class

#endif
namespace LegacyCode
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        public MyClass ()
        {
            Color x = Color.Yellow;  //must not change legacy code
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code to adapt the legacy GDI calls to Xamarin.Forms

```
using System;
//cannot specify 'using Xamarin.Forms;' I want to fully qualify Xamarin.Forms as shown below 'Xamarin.Forms.Color.Yellow;'

namespace FakeGDI
{
    public struct Color
    {

        public static Color Yellow 
        {
            get { 
                return Xamarin.Forms.Color.Yellow;
                ;}
        }
    }
}
```

The solution I'm looking for is to get this to compile and use the Xamarin.Forms Color struct via my Color struct indirectly.

What is needed to allow this type of conversion?

Thanks
Anna

Comment: Please do not collude with other users and re-post the same question multiple times. This is regarded as noise on Stack Overflow. If your question is closed as unanswerable or did not attract responses, then the first thing to do is to *improve the question*; some guidance for this is [given here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Low-quality or unanswerable questions will typically be closed, but can be re-opened if improved or clarified (as appropriate).