# How to fake a library (GDI to Xamarin.Forms) across namespaces and platforms such as reusing Color struct

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, xamarin, code-reuse

Im attempting to reuse legacy Windows GDI code in Xamarin without modifying the legacy GDI code (except using #if). In this specific case I need to use Color from Xamrin.Forms wrapped in my own color struct. I get the error cannot convert as posted in the question header above.

This is the legacy code that is not to be modified (or very little)

```
#if WINDOWS
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;
#else //if Xamarin
using FakeGDI;  //cannot specify 'using Xamarin.Forms;' in legacy class

#endif
namespace LegacyCode
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        public MyClass ()
        {
            Color x = Color.Yellow;  //must not change legacy code
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code to adapt the legacy GDI calls to Xamarin.Forms

```
using System;
//cannot specify 'using Xamarin.Forms;' I want to fully qualify Xamarin.Forms as shown below 'Xamarin.Forms.Color.Yellow;'

namespace FakeGDI
{
    public struct Color
    {

        public static Color Yellow 
        {
            get { 
                return Xamarin.Forms.Color.Yellow;
                ;}
        }
    }
}
```

The solution I'm looking for is to get this to compile and use the Xamarin.Forms Color struct via my Color struct indirectly.

What is needed to allow this type of conversion?

The error I get is: Cannot implicitly convert type `Xamarin.Forms.Color' to`FakeGDI.Color'

Thanks

Comment: _"cannot specify 'using Xamarin.Forms;' in legacy class"_ - Why not?

Comment: Please do not collude with other users and re-post the same question multiple times. This is regarded as noise on Stack Overflow. If your question is closed as unanswerable or did not attract responses, then the first thing to do is to *improve the question*; some guidance for this is [given here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Low-quality or unanswerable questions will typically be closed, but can be re-opened if improved or clarified (as appropriate) (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37505910/?noredirect=1).

Answer (score 0):

It's absolutely not possible to do it in C#.

You're trying to do:

```
StructA a;
StructB b;
a = b;
```

In can never work. It would only be possible if Color were a class, then you could use inheritance.

The constraint that you cannot specify 'using Xamarin.Forms;' in legacy class doesn't leave you any way to do it, because in contrast to languages like JavaScript you can't copy a reference to a class, but only to an object.

However, a solution might be writing the FakeGDI in a different language which does allow copying a reference to a class.

Following is an example how to do it in JavaScript, although you can't really do it in JavaScript, you have to look for a dynamic language which can save its modules as DLLs.

```
module FakeGDI{
  var Xamarin = require('Xamarin.Forms.Color.Yellow');

  module.exports = {
      Color : Xamarin.Forms.Color
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code needs to define the member static properties to be of the correct type. In other words:

```
namespace FakeGDI
{
    public struct Color
    {
        public static Xamarin.Forms.Color Yellow 
        {
            get { 
                return Xamarin.Forms.Color.Yellow;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the `Xamarin.Forms` namespace is applied to the static property itself.

Comment: Thanks Keith. I added it to read as 'public static Xamarin.Forms.Color Yellow' but it did not compile and gave the same error. Did it compile for you ?

Comment: No, your sample code isn't sufficient to reproduce the problem (I've no idea what context this code is expected to operate in). If you could push your minimal repro project(s) into a github repository then it might be possible to better assist.

Answer (score 0):

The exception you are seeing is because the return type of your static property FakeGDI.Color.Yellow is FakeGDI.Color but you return an instance of Xamarin.Forms.Color.

Firstly you want your static properties to return an instance of your Color type since this is the Color type you want your legacy code to reference. You then want to define an implicit opertator that will cast your Color type to the Xamarin Color type wherever your legacy code is expecting a Xamarin.Forms.Color but it supplied with your FakeGCI.Color.

You can make your Color type a wrapper for the Xamarin Color type as follows:

```
namespace FakeGDI
{
    public struct Color 
    {
        private Xamarin.Forms.Color xamarinColor;

        public static Color Yellow
        {
            get
            {
                return new Color(Xamarin.Forms.Color.Yellow);
            }
        }

        private Color(Xamarin.Forms.Color color)
        {
            this.xamarinColor = color;
        }

        public static implicit operator Xamarin.Forms.Color(Color color)
        {
            return color.xamarinColor;
        }

        // although serving no purpose in your snippet, your legacy code will
        // likely need to cast from Xamarin Color to your Color type also
        public static implicit operator Color(Xamarin.Forms.Color color)
        {
            return new Color(color);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Anna glad to help, be grateful if you accepted my answer if it solved your problem :)

Comment: does this use of my Color struct using Xamarin.Forms.Color involve or invoke boxing and unboxing? Isn't it just passing values under my named members? Thanks

Comment: This isn't boxing, boxing really refers to converting a value type to a reference type. What I have provided is almost nothing more than syntactic sugar to get your legacy code to play nicely with the Xamarin.Forms.Color that you are unable to add references for.
edit: note Color is a struct